# How can I convert .py to .exe on Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert my python file to a .exe file.
The issue is, I'm using linux, and I can't use pyinstaller or cx_freeze to make .exe files from
.py.

Is there any way to do it?

I'm using Python 3.7.3 on Debian Linux.

Comment: Is it what your are looking for: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ ?

Comment: Whenever I try it the tab shows up and it says "CONNECTION REFUSED".

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It doesn't work basically.

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR:** You can't.

You should be able to use PyInstaller to create executable files as it is compatible with Linux systems:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requirements.html#gnu-linux

```
pip install pyinstaller
cd /path/to/your/program
pyinstaller --onefile yourscript.py
```

However, at least for pyinstaller, there is no way to bundle an executable file for Windows on a Linux system that I know of:

> The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system and the active
> version of Python. This means that to prepare a distribution for:
>
> - a different OS
> - a different version of Python
> - a 32-bit or 64-bit OS
>
> you run PyInstaller on that OS, under that version of Python. The Python interpreter
> that executes PyInstaller is part of the bundle, and it is specific to the OS and the
> word size.

Source: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `auto-py-to-exe` (on a Linux machine).
Refer to [this](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) link to install it using `pip` and understand how it works.

After `pip` installing it, from the directory containing the Python file to be made into an executable (assuming we are to convert `file.py`):

```
auto-py-to-exe file.py
```

This would open up a browser tab and guide us through the process of generating an `.exe`. It delivers the binaries in an `output` folder (unless mentioned otherwise) located in the same directory that contains `file.py`.